# question closed unfairly

Tags: discussion

The question is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205419/online-gallery-for-uploading-models-for-beginners) and the reason for closing is

> I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Blender

, but it is a question about blender data, blender is explicitly referenced:

> The problem with many sites is, that they don't support blender models
> directly

So blender data is off-limits? I was looking for a site supporting blender data.

Answer (score 8):

The closing of the question was correct for multiple reasons.

1. The goal of your original post with its current wording was a bit unclear. Are you trying to find an existing service that provides this functionality, are you asking how to build this yourself or did you want someone else build this for you?

   1.1. If you are trying to find an existing service, as your post seems to indicate, then this is not a question about Blender and thus off-topic.

   1.2. If you want to build this yourself, the question could be on-topic with several modifications. For instance you could ask how to generate, access and extract thumbnails from .blend files or how to script the automatic rendering of a .blend file to create a final image.

   1.3. If you want someone else to build a web-service for you, this would be off-topic. Building web-applications is not the topic of this Stack Exchange website. Additionally, questions on Stack Exchange need to have a limited scope that can be clearly answered and are potentially useful for other people. Stack Exchange is a Q&A website, we do not provide a service to develop complete applications for free.

Comment: My personal opinion is, that a blender user grows together with his gallery. No gallery, no skill advancement. My goal was 1.1 and highly relevant for a beginner like me. I can't fathom there's no place for a question like this on the blender stackexchange site.

Comment: @user1095108 Blender files need to be rendered to create the final high resolution image that can be presented. This means that .blend files are not like your average image format. Most (digital) artists, regardless of the particular medium or software they use for their art, would create a portfolio of their work either on their own website or on an image hosting website targeted at artists. For instance artstation.com is fairly popular. If you want to share your project files with other people there are a large number of data sharing services and you could put a link in the description.

Comment: Blender files can store thumbnails, but those would only be suitable as a preview, not as a final presentation of the work. You may also want to create several renders of multiple scenes within the project which a single thumbnail obviously cannot capture. Additionally, the artists may want to take the render and perform color grading or other editing tasks in other application before the final image is done. Thus your proposed approach would not be suitable as a portfolio presentation.

Comment: To summarize: You're essentially looking for an image hosting website that has the feature to create private galleries. Since none of this is specific to Blender or uses Blender, it is off-topic.

Comment: Rendering .blend files online is easier than you think `three.js` supports loading blender models. Sure, the quality isn't great, but it works, kind of.

Comment: @user1095108 You're heavily moving the goal post now. That would be an interactive visualization of the 3D model in the browser, like Sketchfab does. The reason this would also be off-topic, is that you can export many different formats from Blender for which there may or may not exists such a service. We generally do not provide recommendations for commercial products or services just because Blender happens to support the data format used by that service.

Comment: Who says the service needed to be commercial? Anyway, some kind of a gallery is a must for every beginner, I believe. Not to show off, you don't have anything to show off at the start. But to track your progress for yourself and I think this topic is not dealt with sufficiently anywhere or I wouldn't have asked my question.

Comment: @user1095108 If you want to discuss how artists can manage a gallery or portfolio for themselves and what kind of software solutions exists for this purpose (pro & cons), you may want to ask about this on https://blenderartists.org/. Stack Exchange is a Q&A website and not well suited for open ended discussions as it is not a forum.